# Native Ads vs Banner (AdMob) : Ram usage

Tags: admob, banner, native-ads

I am trying to decide whether to switch from **banners** to **native ads** for my android application. The

primary concerns are

1. **Revenue**
2. **Ram Usage**

Since AdMob banners use WebView , the ram usage should be higher.

But again, the ads sdk has gone through years of optimisation and thus might pull ahead.

Hence would like to know which one will affect performance more strongly.